# How to run java programs in windows command prompt

Tags: java, compilation

I am not able to run java programmes even after setting the paths in "Environment variables" in the "Advanced System Settings" in windows 10. Plz help!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJkij.png)

Comment: Both `java` and `javac` are running in your screenshot. You ran the commands in reverse order. And it is not clear that you actually have a java source file in that folder.

Comment: Thanks....for the help. Now I am able to run the program.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the directory where the class is saved, before you run the command. For example you hava the class saved in "Users/Bony/java/project/..." you have to type in the command promp "cd Users/Bony/java/project/..." (cd = change directory + path) and then try to run the java class.